# vba ranges and arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, range

hello guys i have a problem in which the user might enter x coordinates and y coordinates in 2 different  and then i must transfer them in two singe dimensional arrays my code is like this but there some errors ( array max =150 values):

```
Dim X as range
dim Y as range
cell as variant
ArrX( 1 to 150) as double
ArrY(1 to 150) as double
i as integer
Xcells as integer
Ycells as integer

Set X = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter X coordinates", Type:=8)
Set Y= Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter Y coordinates",Type:=8)
```

**here i am  trying to count the cells in order to find the actual size of the rane and assign them in another variable but i fail**

```
Xcells = X.Rows.Count
Ycells=Y.Rows.Count

i=0

for each cell in X 
    cell.value=arrX(i)
    i=i+1
next cell

for each cell in Y

    i=0

    cell.value=arrY(i)
    i=i+1
next cell
```

it always throws an error in cell.value

thank you

Comment: the excel says subscript out of range but i cant find my mistake can anyone please help me to identify my mistake?

Comment: What is the value of `i` when it throws the error?

Comment: i think its zero because just before the for i wrote i-=0

Comment: Setting or reading cell values one by one is never a good idea, because for large arrays it is very slow since the worksheet re-calculates on each change. Also the screen has to re-draw. See my answer for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are dimensioned from `1 To 150` that means that 1-150 are valid indexes.  Start `i` at 1 and it should work.

```
i = 1
For Each cell In X
    cell.value = ArrX(i)
    i = i + 1
Next cell

i = 1
For Each cell In Y
    cell.value = ArrY(i)
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

---

However you are not handling the case that the amount of cells in X or Y are higher than 150.  I would dynamically dimension the arrays to the cell count in X and Y.

```
Dim ArrX() As Double
Dim ArrY() As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim Xcells As Integer
Dim Ycells As Integer

Set X = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter X coordinates", Type:=8)
Set Y = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter Y coordinates", Type:=8)

Redim ArrX(X.cells.count)
Redim ArrY(Y.cells.count)
```

Now the Arrays are exactly the size you need them to be. Also you should use `i=0` if you do it this way.

Comment: thak you a just did it a sec before you post your answer and it worked like a charm. one more question i want to count the number of cells in the x y ranges in order to use for a bubble sort later on are my commands above right?

Comment: You can use `X.cells.count` to get the count of cells in the range and you can use `UBound(ArrX)` to get the highest allowed index of Array X and `LBound(ArrX)` to get the lowest.

Comment: For i = 1 To UBound(arrX)


 
       If arrX(i) < arrX(i - 1) Then
      
         temp = arrX(i)
       
         arrX(i) = arrX(i - 1)
 
         arrX(i - 1) = temp
         
         temp = arrY(i)
         arrY(i - 1) = arrY(i)
         arrY(i - 1) = temp
    
 
       End If
 
   
 Next i
       but there all zeros both in x and y column can you help me?

Comment: because you haven't entered any value in your arrays.  All of you arrays contain empty Doubles which are 0. Perhaps you meant to do `ArrX(i) = cell.value`?

Comment: If you have another question about your bubble sort make another question.  We can't start on another problem in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with loops, when you can let Excel do all the work, and really fast:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim arrx() As Variant, arry() As Variant

    Dim rx As Range, ry As Range, i As Integer

    Set rx = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter X coordinates", Type:=8)
    Set ry = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter Y coordinates", Type:=8)

    ReDim arrx(1 To rx.Rows.Count), arry(1 To ry.Rows.Count)
    ' Fill array with values
    For i = 1 To rx.Rows.Count
        arrx(i) = i - 1
        arry(i) = 4 * Rnd() - 2 * Rnd() + 1
    Next i
    ' Export values into worksheet
    rx.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrx)
    ry.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arry)

End Sub
```